# Calling overloaded method with derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

There is something that I don't manage to do with derived class. 
Basically, I have one base class with an interact method, which takes another base class object as an argument. I then have a derived class, and I want it to overload the interact method - derived class objects should interact in their own style. So far so good, using virtual method I get the behaviour I want. However, I would also like to overload the interact method so it can take a derived class object as an argument.

Now, I have an object with a baseclass parameter. When I create such an object with a derived class as parameter and I make it interact with another object also created with a derived class as paramater, it does call the interact method of the derived class (as expected) but consider the method using the baseclass parameter. Is there a way to make it use the other method ?

The code is below, I hope this is clearer with it

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass{
public:
    BaseClass();
    virtual ~Baseclass();

    virtual void interact(BaseClass* interaction_target){std::cout << "base class interaction" << std::endl;}
};

class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
public:
    DerivedClass();
    virtual ~DerivedClass();

    virtual void interact(BaseClass* interaction_target){std::cout << "derived class interaction" << std::endl;}
    virtual void interact(DerivedClass* interaction_target){std::cout << "interaction eased by the fact that two DerivedClass object are interacting" << std::endl;}
};

class MyObject{
protected:
    BaseClass* interactor;
public:
    MyObject(BaseClass* param) : interactor(param){}
    virtual ~MyObject();

    void ObjectInteraction(MyObject interaction_target){interactor->interact(interaction_target.interactor);}
};

int main(){

MyObject first_obj(new DerivedClass());
MyObject sec_obj(new DerivedClass());

first_obj.ObjectInteraction(sec_obj); // prints derived class interactions, whereas I would like
// it to use the second method ie. interact(DerivedClass*)
return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway to do this at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  What you're trying to do here is called "double dispatch," or more generally, "[multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B)."  C++ doesn't support it directly (some languages do), but you can implement it yourself using the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).