# How do I overload a function with a parameter with a type that is a child class of the base parameter?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, abstract-class, derived-class

If I have a base abstract class with a function that takes it's own class as a parameter:

```
class Component abstract
{
public:
    virtual bool Method(Component& other) = 0;
};
```

And I have a child class which overrides and overloads this function to take a parameter of *its class*:

```
class DerivedComponent : public Component
{
public:
    virtual bool Method(Component& other) override;
    virtual bool Method(DerivedComponent& other);
};
```

And I use these as components of another class, as such:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Component* m_component;
public:
    Foo()
    {
        m_component = new DerivedComponent();
    }

    Component* GetComponent()
    {
        return m_component;
    }
};
```

And I call the component's method, passing in `Foo`'s component:

```
Foo foo1 = Foo();
Foo foo2 = Foo();
foo1.GetComponent()->Method(*foo2.GetComponent());
```

Why does it call the `DerivedComponent`'s first un-overloaded method, `Method(Component& other)`, instead of `Method(DerivedComponent& other)`?

Comment: Because `*foo2.GetComponent()` is a `Component`, so that matches the first overload. Overload resolution is based on static types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling overloaded method with derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698355/calling-overloaded-method-with-derived-class)

Comment: What is your actual goal here?  This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DerivedComponent` declares two overloads of `Method`: one that that takes a `Component &` and one that takes a `DerivedComponent &`.

But overloading is always resolved statically. That is, the compiler has to decide *at compile time* which overloaded function is going to be called. Since that resolution happens a compile time, it's based on information that's available at compile time: the static type of pointer/reference the itself, not the dynamic type of the object to which it points/refers.

There is a fairly clean way to deal with it though--the visitor pattern (or at least a close variant of it).

To implement it we, add another virtual function (which I've called `Dispatch`). When we use `Method`, it calls `Dispatch` on the object that was passed (by reference). So, we can get behavior that depends on both the object that did the calling and the the object that was passed. Here's a somewhat expanded version of your demo, showing virtual behavior for both the invoking object, and the passed object:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Component
{
public:
    virtual void Method(Component& other) { 
        std::cout << this->Dispatch() << "(" << other.Dispatch() << ")\n";
    }

    virtual std::string Dispatch() { return "Component"; };
};

class DerivedComponent : public Component
{
public:
    std::string Dispatch() override { return "Derived"; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Component {
    std::string Dispatch() override { return "Derived2"; }
};

// making this a template so it's easy to create `Foo`s that create and 
// manage any of the preceding types.
template <class T>
class Foo
{
private:
    Component* m_component;
public:
    Foo()
    {
        m_component = new T;
    }

    Component* GetComponent()
    {
        return m_component;
    }
};

int main() { 
    Foo<Component> foo;
    Foo<DerivedComponent> foo1;
    Foo<Derived2> foo2;

    foo.GetComponent()->Method(*foo1.GetComponent());
    foo1.GetComponent()->Method(*foo2.GetComponent());
    foo2.GetComponent()->Method(*foo.GetComponent());
}
```

Result:

```
Component(Derived)
Derived(Derived2)
Derived2(Component)
```

Of course, in real use we need to handle a few other things--`Foo` probably needs a dtor to destroy the `Component` (or derived) object it creates. It probably also needs to do something with respect to copying, moving and assignment (but exactly what it should do is rather a separate question). Since we're using it as a base class, and probably going to destroy derived objects via a pointer/reference to the base, `Component` needs a virtual `dtor`. (And there may easily be a few more things that don't occur to me at the moment--but we're using inheritance, so we need to do all the usual inheritance "stuff").

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not know you are using a derived type, and will not automatically up-cast a pointer to that type. `GetComponent` returns a `Component*`. That can be *any* subclass, not just a `DerivedComponent*`.

If you *know* the `Component*` is actually a `DerivedComponent*`, you can explicitly cast it yourself:

```
auto derivedComponent1 = static_cast<DerivedComponent&>(*foo1.GetComponent());
auto derivedComponent2 = static_cast<DerivedComponent&>(*foo2.GetComponent());
derivedComponent1.Method(derivedComponent2);
```

If you *don't know*, and RTTI is enabled, then you can dynamic_cast:

```
auto derivedComponent1 = dynamic_cast<DerivedComponent*>(foo1.GetComponent());
auto derivedComponent2 = dynamic_cast<DerivedComponent*>(foo2.GetComponent());
if (derivedComponent1 && derivedComponent2)
    derivedComponent1->Method(*derivedComponent2);
```

As you can see from the mess above, this is not particularly ideal. Typically that points to a more fundamental issue with your design that you may want to reconsider.

At the very least, if you need special behavior for a `DerivedComponent`, you could move the dynamic_cast stuff into your implementation instead of expecting the caller to do it:

```
class DerivedComponent : public Component
{
public:
    bool Method(Component& other) override
    {
        auto derivedComponent = dynamic_cast<DerivedComponent*>(&other);
        if (derivedComponent) {
            return Method(*derivedComponent);
        }

        // default behavior, perhaps invoking superclass method but
        // in this case that is pure virtual so I guess do nothing.
        return false;
    }

    virtual bool Method(DerivedComponent& other)
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

And the above will now behave how you expected with the following:

```
foo1.GetComponent()->Method(*foo2.GetComponent());
```